# Questions regarding Locked Post

Tags: support

My yesterday's post 
https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/45882/complain-or-endure
is locked

I request an edit to make it re-open. In my understanding, the question does not generalize to other people like me, and I can fix it. I will remove disturbing contents regarding my health issues. Please indicate any additional problem that I have to edit.

Otherwise, if it can be be re-opened, please help to delete the original post. In any case, thanks

Comment: I was mystified about why it was locked myself, and would like to hear an explanation.

Comment: @jakebeal we followed he advice given here: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6256/do-we-have-any-responsibility-to-take-any-action-if-someone-says-theyre-thinkin/6258#6258

Comment: @ aeismail thank you for the nice clean-up/rearranging you did.  Perhaps you would like to delete my obsolete question now?  I don't seem to be able to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I do not generally like people asking an an an already closed question again, in this case I would prefer to see you simply ask the question as a new question in a better form. There are no answers to be lost and the comment does not seem that vital.